# Compose image with a text box and a picture

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I want to create an A4 picture (2480x3508) with a picture at the bottom and a text box at the top. Of course, I want everything to be centered and aligned.

Example:

```
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|  +---------------------------+  |
|  |         TEXT BOX          |  |   The TEXT BOX size is 2352x376 pixels
|  +---------------------------+  |   Its offset is +64+64 pixels
|                                 |
|  +---------------------------+  |
|  |                           |  |
|  |                           |  |
|  |                           |  |
|  |         PICTURE           |  |   The PICTURE size is 2352x2940 pixels
|  |                           |  |   Its offset is +64+504 pixels
|  |                           |  |
|  +---------------------------+  |
|                                 |
+---------------------------------+
```

Using imagemagick, can it be done in one line ? Or should I do this in to steps ?

I try to use `montage` with a title, but it is restricted to a single line and you cannot really control test formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in ImageMagick in one command line. What version of Imagemagick are you using. If IM 6 do the following. If IM 7 change convert to magick.

```
convert -size 2480x3508 xc:white \( -size 2352x376 -background pink -gravity center -fill black -font arial label:"TEXT BOX" \) -gravity northwest -geometry +64+64 -compose over -composite \( logo: -resize 2352x2940! \) -geometry +64+504 -compose over -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

In the command replace ( logo: -resize 2352x2940! ) with your actual image. Also change the text you want to use in place of what I used and also change the pink background to whatever color you want. If using Windows remove the \ from the ( and ) so that you only have ( and ). Be sure you have spaces before and after the parens with or without the \ escape.

If your text is multi-line, then use caption: rather than label:

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert and http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/ and http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis